# Keyboard hook for dummies

Tags: autohotkey

Could somebody give me a very basic explanation of how the keyboard hook works in autohotkey? Or direct me to a post or page somewhere. I still don't  grasp the concept. Maybe I just haven't read enough. Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the specific command `#InstallKeybdHook`? Or are you just asking how to catch keys using AutoHotkey?

Comment: Hi, sorry about the off-topic thing. Yes it's the command above I want to learn more about, but I guess I should rather knuckle down to some reading and get to understand the concepts. I use ahk extensively since I suffer from permanent RSI and need to reprogram my keyboard extensively. (No spying agenda.) I hope the hook can help extend the functionalities currently available. I'll have a look at the link below.

Comment: Extensively, though, meaning quantity not quality ... I program many keys but without real sophistication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I's explained in the documentation: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm

> The keyboard hook monitors keystrokes for the purpose of activating
>   hotstrings and any keyboard hotkeys not supported by RegisterHotkey
>   (which is a function built into the operating system). It also
>   supports a few other features such as the Input command.